# Ubuntu 16.04 ssh lag issues

Tags: server, ssh, 16.04

really frustrating bug right now, that I cannot find the cause of.

So I have a server on digitalocean that I serve my site on. but since switching from windows to Ubuntu 16.04 there has been random ssh lag issues. It's on and off.

The lag not only happens at login. (I have tried adding UseDNS no). Even when I eventually do get logged in, I cannot type any command literary takes a good 10 to 20 secs to show up.

I did a traceroute but have no idea what it means and how to fix this problem.

```
traceroute "ip"
traceroute to "ip" ("ip"), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  172.23.80.49 (172.23.80.49)  80.367 ms  127.421 ms  127.479 ms
 4  mai-b1-link.telia.net (213.248.83.161)  293.276 ms mai-b1-link.telia.net (213.248.76.89)  293.319 ms mai-b1-link.telia.net (213.248.83.161)  293.389 ms
 5  ash-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.113.200)  293.391 ms * *
 6  nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (62.115.137.65)  293.514 ms nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.134.126)  213.196 ms nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (62.115.137.65)  166.349 ms
 7  nyk-b3-link.telia.net (62.115.112.253)  180.545 ms nyk-b3-link.telia.net (80.239.147.138)  204.523 ms nyk-b3-link.telia.net (80.91.247.19)  204.509 ms
 8  digitalocean-ic-306498-nyk-b3.c.telia.net (62.115.45.10)  204.608 ms  204.596 ms *
 9  162.243.188.234 (162.243.188.234)  205.152 ms 162.243.188.230 (162.243.188.230)  205.032 ms  190.648 ms
10  "ip" ("ip")  59.939 ms  105.458 ms  116.519 ms
$ traceroute -n "ip"
traceroute to "ip" ("ip"), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  172.23.80.49  88.487 ms  131.767 ms  131.804 ms
 4  213.248.76.89  217.216 ms 213.248.83.161  217.284 ms 213.248.76.89  217.320 ms
 5  62.115.113.200  267.056 ms 62.115.113.198  267.865 ms  267.904 ms
 6  213.155.134.148  267.909 ms 213.155.133.8  295.299 ms 62.115.134.110  185.072 ms
 7  80.239.147.132  184.852 ms 80.239.147.134  165.540 ms 62.115.112.251  166.324 ms
 8  62.115.45.6  166.163 ms  148.741 ms  148.065 ms
 9  162.243.188.230  147.985 ms  213.959 ms 162.243.188.234  165.199 ms
10  "ip"  165.055 ms  150.840 ms  158.119 ms
```

also my friends running arch has a little lag but it's usable.

"-vvv" flag output:

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to "ip" (["ip"]:305).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JOB
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env NODE_PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env PAPERSIZE
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SESSIONTYPE
debug3: Ignored env GTK2_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_INSTANCE
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_EVENTS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env COMPIZ_BIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env INSTANCE
debug3: Ignored env UPSTART_JOB
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

freezes right by the last line in the output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless 'top' shows a CPU usage hovering around 100%, your lag is coming from a networking issue of some form.

Contact DigitalOcean if you have concerns about the level of service they are providing.